# VideoPlayer becomes black when dismissing a miniplayer in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, video-player, dismiss, flutter-video-player

I have a `miniplayer` where I have a video widget (I use [better_player](https://pub.dev/packages/better_player) which depends on [chewie](https://pub.dev/packages/chewie) and [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player)). Everything works great unless I want to dismiss the miniplayer. The video is replaced with a black screen. I did some debugging and found out that for some reason the `dispose()` method is called on my `video_widget` twice (when I start dismissing and when I end dismissing my miniplayer). Below is a video that shows this behavior:

[image]

Could you help me with fixing this issue?

**EDIT**

I did some more debugging and found out that it is probably related to the `video widget` or better_player package. Also, I found out that when using chewie behavior is nearly the same but with chewie when I start dismissing video gets black for a millisecond and then initializes again and starts playing from the beginning. Here is the code of my `video widget class.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:cook_it/screens/longs_page/providers/providers.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:better_player/better_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';


class LongsVideoItem extends StatefulWidget {
  const LongsVideoItem({Key? key }) : super(key: key);


  @override
  _LongsVideoItemState createState() => _LongsVideoItemState();
}

class _LongsVideoItemState extends State<LongsVideoItem> {

  void _toggleVideoControls(bool show){

    if (show){
      _betterPlayerController.setControlsEnabled(true);
    }else{
      _betterPlayerController.setControlsEnabled(false);

    }
  }

  Future _saveAssetVideoToFile() async {
    final content = await rootBundle.load("assets/videos/second.mp4");
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final file = File("${directory.path}/second.mp4");
    _directory = "${directory.path}/second.mp4";
    file.writeAsBytesSync(content.buffer.asUint8List());
  }

  BetterPlayerController _betterPlayerController = BetterPlayerController(const BetterPlayerConfiguration());

  dynamic _directory;


  @override
  void initState() {

    _saveAssetVideoToFile().then((value) {
      final BetterPlayerDataSource betterPlayerDataSource = BetterPlayerDataSource(
        BetterPlayerDataSourceType.file,
        _directory.toString(),
      );
      _betterPlayerController = BetterPlayerController(
        const BetterPlayerConfiguration(
          deviceOrientationsAfterFullScreen: [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp],
          aspectRatio: 16/9,
          autoPlay: true,
          controlsConfiguration:  BetterPlayerControlsConfiguration(showControlsOnInitialize: false),
        ),
        betterPlayerDataSource: betterPlayerDataSource,
      );
    });
    
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Consumer(
      
      builder: (context, watch, _){

        
        if (watch(videoShowControlsProvider).state == true){
          _toggleVideoControls(true);
        }else if (watch(videoShowControlsProvider).state == false){
          _toggleVideoControls(false);
        }

          return BetterPlayer(controller: _betterPlayerController,);
    
      }
    );
  }
}
```

***here are the logs when I start dismissing***

```
I/ExoPlayerImpl(16667): Release cd87770 [ExoPlayerLib/2.14.1] [HWCLT, CLT-L29, HUAWEI, 28] [goog.exo.core]
W/ACodec  (16667): forcing OMX state to Idle when received shutdown in ExecutingState
3
E/BufferQueueProducer(16667): [SurfaceTexture-0-16667-145] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
I/chatty  (16667): uid=10234(com.example.cook_it) JNISurfaceTextu identical 10 lines
E/BufferQueueProducer(16667): [SurfaceTexture-0-16667-145] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
D/SurfaceUtils(16667): disconnecting from surface 0x797bec7010, reason disconnectFromSurface
I/ExoPlayerImpl(16667): Init 8b84e21 [ExoPlayerLib/2.14.1] [HWCLT, CLT-L29, HUAWEI, 28]
V/AudioManager(16667): getStreamVolume  treamType: 3
V/AudioManager(16667): isStreamMute   streamType: 3
V/AudioManager(16667): getStreamMaxVolume  treamType: 3
E/        (16667): [ZeroHung]zrhung_get_config: Get config failed for wp[0x0008]
I/OMXClient(16667): IOmx service obtained
I/ACodec  (16667): In onAllocateComponent create compenent, codec name: OMX.hisi.video.decoder.avc
D/SurfaceUtils(16667): connecting to surface 0x797c027010, reason connectToSurface
I/MediaCodec(16667): [OMX.hisi.video.decoder.avc] setting surface generation to 17067154
D/SurfaceUtils(16667): disconnecting from surface 0x797c027010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
D/SurfaceUtils(16667): connecting to surface 0x797c027010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
E/ACodec  (16667): [OMX.hisi.video.decoder.avc] setPortMode on output to DynamicANWBuffer failed w/ err -2147483648
I/HwExtendedCodec(16667): mime is [video/avc] at setVideoFormat
I/ACodec  (16667): codec does not support config priority (err -22)
2
I/ACodec  (16667): [OMX.hisi.video.decoder.avc] got color aspects (R:2(Limited), P:1(BT709_5), M:1(BT709_5), T:3(SMPTE170M)) err=0(NO_ERROR)
I/ACodec  (16667): [OMX.hisi.video.decoder.avc] using color aspects (R:2(Limited), P:1(BT709_5), M:1(BT709_5), T:3(SMPTE170M)) and dataspace 0x104
I/ACodec  (16667): onStart
D/SurfaceUtils(16667): disconnecting from surface 0x797c027010, reason setNativeWindowSizeFormatAndUsage
D/SurfaceUtils(16667): connecting to surface 0x797c027010, reason setNativeWindowSizeFormatAndUsage
D/SurfaceUtils(16667): set up nativeWindow 0x797c027010 for 1920x1080, color 0x30d, rotation 0, usage 0x20002900
6
W/MapperHal(16667): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
2
I/ACodec  (16667): [OMX.hisi.video.decoder.avc] got color aspects (R:2(Limited), P:1(BT709_5), M:1(BT709_5), T:3(SMPTE170M)) err=0(NO_ERROR)
I/ACodec  (16667): [OMX.hisi.video.decoder.avc] using color aspects (R:2(Limited), P:1(BT709_5), M:1(BT709_5), T:3(SMPTE170M)) and dataspace 0x104
2
I/ACodec  (16667): [OMX.hisi.video.decoder.avc] got color aspects (R:2(Limited), P:1(BT709_5), M:1(BT709_5), T:3(SMPTE170M)) err=0(NO_ERROR)
I/ACodec  (16667): [OMX.hisi.video.decoder.avc] using color aspects (R:2(Limited), P:1(BT709_5), M:1(BT709_5), T:3(SMPTE170M)) and dataspace 0x104
D/SurfaceUtils(16667): disconnecting from surface 0x797c027010, reason setNativeWindowSizeFormatAndUsage
D/SurfaceUtils(16667): connecting to surface 0x797c027010, reason setNativeWindowSizeFormatAndUsage
D/SurfaceUtils(16667): set up nativeWindow 0x797c027010 for 1920x1088, color 0x30d, rotation 0, usage 0x20002900
W/ACodec  (16667): [OMX.hisi.video.decoder.avc] setting nBufferCountActual to 19 failed: -2147483648
18
W/MapperHal(16667): buffer descriptor with invalid usage bits 0x2000
I/ACodec  (16667): date space update : 0x104
```

I believe that for some reason this widget calls the `dispose()` method when I start dismissing. But why is that happening and how can I prevent that from happening?

Comment: better to provided some code.

Comment: @JerryZhou I added my code and the logs

Comment: to make sure if it call `dispose`,  you can print some log in that function `void dispose() {`

Comment: @JerryZhou I did it and it printed logs two times, when I started and when I ended dismissing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem was in the miniplayer package. In case someone has the same problem comment here and I will explain how to fix it.

Comment: how do you solve this ? please

Comment: @MohammedFahjan there is a line of code in the miniplayer.dart file in the miniplayer package `if (value == 0) return child!;` that needs to be deleted. So I downloaded this package so that I have it in my project and deleted this line

Comment: The error appears because miniplayer returns new widget when you start to dismiss (and the video widget restarts). However this widget is the same as the one it returns normally.  So there is no need to return another widget. That's why you need to delete the line of code that I mentioned above.